# Continue a parsing in another class ElementTree Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

In my first class i parse my xml file like this :

```
class ListActeurs():
    fonction_key = "DiagramElements"
    def __init__(self):

         self.list_acteurs = []

         root = ElementTree.parse("D:\\Users\T0211254\MyApp\Bundle CUD-CAPELLA 431\melody\eclipse\workspace\XML2\XML2.aird").getroot()
         for diagram in self.root:
             if ListActeurs.diagramme_key in diagram.tag:
                self.diagram_name = diagram.attrib.get('name')
                self.diagram_id = diagram.get('{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id')
                self.dict_diagrams[self.diagram_name] = self.diagram_id
                for owned in diagram:
                    if ListActeurs.acteur_key in owned.tag:
                        self.acteur_name = owned.attrib.get('name')  # Récupération des noms des acteurs
                        self.acteur_id = owned.get('{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id')  # Récupération des id's des acteurs
                        print(self.acteur_name, '==>', self.acteur_id)
                        for elements in owned:
                            if ListActeurs.fonction_key in elements.tag:
                                self.fonctions_name = elements.attrib.get('name')  # Récupération des noms des fonctions
                                self.fonctions_id = elements.get('{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id')  # Récupération des ID's des fonctions
                                self.data_fonctions = ElementTree.tostring(elements)
                                self.list_acteurs.append(Acteur(self.fonctions_name, self.fonctions_id, self.data_fonctions))
```

At the end i create an Object Acteur() with differents attributes including "self.data_fonction" which contains a part of the xml file in a String variable.

I would like to continue to parse this part of xml in another class. I tried this :

```
class Acteur() :

def __init__(self, fonctions_name, fonctions_id, data_fonctions):

    self.fonctions_name = str(fonctions_name)
    self.fonctions_id = str(fonctions_id)
    self.data_fonctions = str(data_fonctions)
    elements = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data_fonctions))
    for ports in elements :
        ports_name = ports.attrib.get('name')
        print(ports_name)
```

But there is an error :

```
for ports in elements :
TypeError: 'ElementTree' object is not iterable
```

However I can't use the ElementTree fonction parse() because it's not anymore a file. How can i do that ? I have thinking of creating an xml file and to put "self.data_fonction" in it et to parse this xml file but is there any better method to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found ! data_fonctions was a bytes object i just encoded it :

```
self.data_fonctions = ElementTree.tostring(elements)
self.data_fonctions_string = self.data_fonctions.decode("utf-8")
```

to make it String and put it in a variable. And so i could ET.fromstring() this variable to my part of xml code !

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

While parsing xml file you have created ElementTree object.
You have to use instance of ElementTree object ('root' in your code example) in order to iterate.

So basically just use:

```
for child in root:
    print child.tag, child.attrib
```

instead of:

```
elements = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data_fonctions))
for ports in elements :
    ports_name = ports.attrib.get('name')
    print(ports_name)
```

Comment: If i'm not wrong if i use this, it will parse the entire xml file one more time and not just "data_fonctions" which contains just a little part of the xml file ?

Comment: Since you have already 'root' object that contains xml you will not parse xml one more time.

Comment: I have edited my code. I meant if i restart from the beginning (root) i have to develop  my tree again until "elements" branch. I think I probably don't understand your point of view.